# (Excel VBA) Issue With Report generate code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm totally new to VBA and would like to do some code for generating report.

The below Code is what i have try to do myself but failed to generate what i want
is just showing compile error : Invalid Qualifier.

What i would like to do is 1st search in a sheet and compare date than if found get all the data and show in a sheet name Report.
Than go to the next sheet available to search for the same date and than show on Report also.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim SheetName As String
Dim FoundCell As Excel.Range
Dim iRow As Long
Dim number As Integer
Dim Row As Long

number = 0
ws1 = "Report"

For Each Sheet In test.Worksheets
SheetName = Sheet.Name

Set FoundCell = SheetName.Range("A:A").Find(what:=reportDate.Value,     lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
  Row = FoundCell.Row
  iRow = ws1.Cells.Find(what:="*", After:=ws.Range("b1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = number + 1
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = SheetName
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Row, 2)
  .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Row, 3)
  .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Row, 4)
  .Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Row, 5)
  .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Row, 6)
  .Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Row, 7)
  .Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Row, 8)
  .Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Row, 9)
  .Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Row, 10)
  .Cells(iRow, 12).Value = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Row, 11)
  .Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Row, 12)
  .Cells(iRow, 14).Value = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Row, 13)
  .Cells(iRow, 15).Value = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Row, 14)
  .Cells(iRow, 16).Value = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Row, 15)

Else

End If

Next Sheet


End Sub
```

@Branislav Kollár

I have just used the code you given and done some changes on it, now there is a problem where there is no error message but is not generating any output on the report sheet.

```
Private Sub GenerateBtn_Click()

Dim wsReport As Worksheet
Dim FoundCell As Excel.Range
Dim iRow As Long
Dim number As Long
Dim lngRow As Long 'changed, you shouldn't use keywords as variable names
Dim objEachSheet As Worksheet 'added
Dim FindDate As Date


FindDate = reportDate.Value


number = 1

Set wsReport = Sheets("Report") 'changed

For Each objEachSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'changed variable

    Set FoundCell = objEachSheet.Range("A:A").Find(what:=FindDate, lookat:=xlWhole)     'changed sheet reference; expecting trouble here

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        With wsReport
            lngRow = FoundCell.Row
            iRow = .Cells.Find(what:="*", After:=.Range("b1"),         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1 'changed
            'line above can cause logical errors
            .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = number
            .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = objEachSheet.Name
            .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = objEachSheet.Cells(lngRow, 2)

    End With


    End If
number = number + 1
Next objEachSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Try stepping through the code (using F8), and verify that the `If Not FoundCell Is Nothing` is `True` (in other words, that the lines inside the If statement are evaluated).

Comment: One more thing.Use this line `FindDate = Range("reportDate").Value` instead of `FindDate = reportDate.Value`

Comment: @Branislav Tried the     FindDate = Range("reportDate").Value but it came out error Runtime error "1004" Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.

About the F8 im not sure on how to verify >.<

Comment: **About error:** I thought you had the "reportDate" as a named range in your workbook. If not, make it so or you can use a cell reference i.e. :  `FindDate = Range("A5").Value`, of course change it to cell where your date is. **About F8:** In the Visual Basic environment, click anywhere between the `Sub` and `End Sub` and press F8, it will run the code one line after another, so long as you keep pressing F8 key. You can also find this as a button in View > Toolbars > Debug > "*Step Into*"

Comment: reportDate is a value from the Calender in the toolbox. and also for the **F8** , is already showing the steps is working. just is not showing any data @_@...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a sample workbook, click the link to open it.

[Chia fatt Tan workbook example](https://www.amazon.ca/clouddrive/share/pOdxz-Efs0OEbFgSDuWOoKTvFPKUoJPeQ0sqsI9bpPA?ref_=cd_share_link_copy_flash)

This is the code,

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, s As String
    Dim rows As Long, rng As Range, c As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("Report")
    For Each sh In Sheets
        If sh.Name <> ws.Name Then
            With sh
                Rws = .Cells(.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row'finds last row in the sh
                Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rws, 1))'sets the range to loop
                s = reportDate

                For Each c In rng.Cells'start loop
                    If c.Value = s Then
                        lstrow = ws.Cells(ws.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                        ws.Cells(lstrow + 1, "A") = lstrow
                        ws.Cells(lstrow + 1, "B") = sh.Name

                        .Range(.Cells(c.Row, "B"), .Cells(c.Row, "P")).Copy
                        ws.Cells(lstrow + 1, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    End If
                Next c
            End With
        End If
    Next sh

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your time on doing the workbook example, but when i try with the workbook u provided, still i not able to generate any details even with the workbook example you provided, only the "header 1" is able to generate, others date is not able to generate even there is data in it.

Comment: Link us to an example.

Comment: i had resolve all the thing using the example you provided, thanks alot, but i came to another issue, if in the same sheets i have 2 same date but different data, how can i shows 2 in the report instead the first one only the vba found

Comment: If the original question has been resolved then please mark it as the answer. I will edit the code for you shortly..

Comment: Code has been changed to loop through column A in each sheet to find the date selected.

Comment: Thanks for the code, do you mind adding comment so that i know which is the line that is for the loop through column A ? im abit confuse on it >.<

Answer (score 1):

Is this in a UserForm?

```
ws1 = "Report"
```

should be

```
set ws1=sheets("Report")
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code as follows:

- Deleted some unnecessary variables
- Changed some variables
- Set the worksheet object properly
- Used with block statements where appropriate
- Merged multiple lines into single one
- Added comments for further thinking and warnings

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'change the name of the button, you won't regret it in long run

Dim wsReport As Worksheet
Dim FoundCell As Excel.Range
Dim iRow As Long
Dim number As Integer
Dim lngRow As Long 'changed, you shouldn't use keywords as variable names
Dim objEachSheet As Worksheet 'added

Set wsReport = Sheets("Report") 'changed

For Each objEachSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'changed variable

    Set FoundCell = objEachSheet.Range("A:A").Find(what:=reportDate.Value, lookat:=xlWhole) 'changed sheet reference; expecting trouble here

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        With wsReport
            lngRow = FoundCell.Row
            iRow = .Cells.Find(what:="*", After:=.Range("b1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1 'changed
            'line above can cause logical errors
            number = number + 1
            .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = number
            .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = objEachSheet.Name
        End With

        With objEachSheet
          .Range(.Cells(lngRow, 2), .Cells(lngRow, 15)).Copy wsReport.Cells(iRow, 3)
        End With
    End If
Next objEachSheet

End Sub
```

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: As tried with your code is still provide me error Run time error "424"; object required.

the number = number + 1 is for me to show number on Report sheet row A

Example :

Report sheet
1 xxx xxx xxx
2 xxx xxx xxx
The 1 and 2 is the number.

Comment: @chiafattTan Which line is giving the error? I reordered the counter line in code, since you confirmed you want to use it.

Comment: ~ check on top ~ i have edited my question :) ~ thanks for helping